# Counting how many natural numbers satisfy a given condition.

Tags: natural-numbers

I've defined a sequence of sequences $\{x^n\}$ as follows

$x^1=(1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,...)$

$x^2=(1,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,....)$

$x^3=(1,2,3^2,4^2,5^2,...)$

.

.

.

and for each $n$ fixed, I am trying to determine $|\{j: x^n_{j} \leq k\}|$. In other words, for a sequence $x^n$, if I look at the term $x^n_{k}$, I want to calculate how many terms of the sequence satisfy $x^n_{j} \leq k$.

Comment: @peterwhy: right, sorry. Maybe that's a typo though.

Comment: Sorry, what an idiot, it was a typo.

Comment: If $k \geqslant n^2$, there are $\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor$ terms, otherwise $\min\{n-1,k\}$.

Comment: I got that estimate just for the sequence $x^1$, I was trying to understand what happens with $x^n$ for an arbitrary $n$, thanks.

Comment: More precisely, if $k<0$ then $0$, if $0\le k<n^2$ then $\min(n-1, \lfloor k\rfloor)$, if $k\ge n^2$ then $\lfloor \sqrt k\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that as long as you are in the squares, you have the same number of terms. The term $p^2$ is the $p^{\text{th}}$ term. If you are in the first powers, $q$ is the $q^{\text{th}}$ term. When are you in each regime?